# Given a large list of URLs, What's the best method of data mining to group the URLs together into patterns or regExs?

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching, machine-learning, data-mining, information-retrieval

I've got a list of 1 million URLs and I'd like to cluster similar URLs together. The output of the process would be a list of regular expressions or patterns. Ideally I'd like to use Ruby to derive the data. My initial thoughts flow toward using a Machine Learning classifier, but I'm not sure where to start or what data mining technique to use.

Possible example:

### Input:

```
http://www.example.com/folder-A/file.html
http://www.example.com/folder-A/dude.html
http://www.example.com/folder-B/huh.html
http://www.example.com/folder-C/what-ever.html
```

### Output:

```
http://www\.example\.com/folder-A/[a-z]\.html
http://www\.example\.com/folder-[A-C]/[-a-z]\.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# the following is a CPAN module requiring independent installation:
use Regexp::Assemble;

my @url_list = qw(
    http://www.example.com/folder-A/file.html
    http://www.example.com/folder-A/dude.html
    http://www.example.com/folder-B/huh.html
    http://www.example.com/folder-C/what-ever.html
);

my $asm = Regexp::Assemble->new;
for my $url (@url_list) {
    $asm->add($url);
}

my $pat = $asm->re;
for ($pat) {
    s/^.*?://;
    s/\)$//;
}

print "$pat\n";
```

when run, duly prints out:

```
http://www.example.com/folder-(?:A/(?:dud|fil)e|C/what-ever|B/huh).html
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use this(http://www.brics.dk/automaton/) automaton library to create or operation of several string and then optimize automaton in this case you will just get generilized one Regular expression.

More simple solution is to use prefix optimization to extract similar first part, for this look at this example http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/wiki/RegexpOptimization.

Unfortunately all this stuff is done for java, but of course generated regexp can be used in any regular expression engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you should parse a URL with a regular expression then take a look at the [IETF's RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

> RFC 2396                   URI Generic Syntax                August
>   1998
>
> B. Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression
>
> As described in Section 4.3, the generic URI syntax is not
>   sufficient    to disambiguate the components of some forms of URI. 
>   Since the    "greedy algorithm" described in that section is identical
>   to the    disambiguation method used by POSIX regular expressions, it
>   is    natural and commonplace to use a regular expression for parsing
>   the    potential four components and fragment identifier of a URI
>   reference.
>
> The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
>   URI    reference into its components.
>
> ```
>   ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>    12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> The numbers in the second line above are only to assist
>   readability;    they indicate the reference points for each
>   subexpression (i.e., each    paired parenthesis).  We refer to the
>   value matched for subexpression     as $.  For example, matching
>   the above expression to
>
> ```
>   http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
> ```
>
> results in the following subexpression matches:
>
> ```
>   $1 = http:
>   $2 = http
>   $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>   $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>   $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>   $6 = <undefined>
>   $7 = <undefined>
>   $8 = #Related
>   $9 = Related
> ```
>
> where  indicates that the component is not present, as
>   is    the case for the query component in the above example. 
>   Therefore, we    can determine the value of the four components and
>   fragment as
>
> ```
>   scheme    = $2
>   authority = $4
>   path      = $5
>   query     = $7
>   fragment  = $9
> ```
>
> and, going in the opposite direction, we can recreate a URI
>   reference    from its components using the algorithm in step 7 of
>   Section 5.2.

From there you should be able to compare the fragments of the URL and identify patterns.

Comment: To clarify, the question is less about how to parse URLs but more the, how to identify the patterns in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but it sounds like something you could do with a map/reduce type setup. Partition your data in smaller chunks, group each chunk by "root" (whatever you mean by that, I assume "authority" or maybe "scheme" + "authority") and then merge the groups in the reduce stage.

Comment: I'll clarify the question. The part that I'm interested in is how to "chunk" or group together URLs and find the patterns that make up the groups.